# django ForeignKey relation how to get data other tables

Tags: django, relation

I have 3 models

```
class product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class order(models.Model):
  order_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class order_products(models.Model):
  order_id = models.ForeignKey(order )
  product_id = models.ForeignKey(product )
```

One order has multiple products

is this relation is correct and if it is correct then if i get all the order then how can i get it related product data?

Comment: Why do you make the `ForeignKey`s nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relation. You can also specify this without an intermediate model with a `ManyToManyField`, or specify one on top of this model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='OrderProduct',
        related_name='orders'
    )

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
  order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here the `ManyToManyField` will thus consult the `OrderProduct` model to obtain the related `Product`s (or `Order`s for a given `Product`). You can then access these more conveniently with:

```
myorder.products.all()
```

Where *`myorder`* is a `Order` object.

Some remarks:

1. it is not clear why you used `null=True`. This would result in `OrderProduct`s that no longer point to an `Order` or `Product`;
2. Models are normally written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so `OrderProduct`, not `order_product`;
3. Normally a `ForeignKey` has no `_id` suffix in its name, since Django will automatically add an `_id` suffix to field to generate a database field;
4. you can later add a `quantity` field in the `OrderProduct` model to specify how many times the product has been ordered in a single `Order`, this makes the data more compact.

Comment: related_name='orders' is this correct ... orders or order ?

Comment: @JaskaransinghRajal: `orders` since it is the name of the relation in reverse, and a `Product` can belong to *many* `Order`s (so plural).

Comment: i want to add  product price ,  in OrderProduct model is it correct?

Comment: @JaskaransinghRajal: if a price is related to a product, you store this in the `Product` model. If it is specific to an order *and* product, in the `OrderProduct`.

Comment: no every order has diff price if A order has product xyz then it has 10 and if b order has product xyz then 20

Comment: on every order price change so is it can store

Comment: @JaskaransinghRajal: then you can indeed store this in the `OrderProduct` model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63936902/how-can-i-get-data-manytomay-relation-from-3-tables-django can you ans this