# how can i get data manytomay relation from 3 tables django

Tags: django, relation

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='OrderProduct',
        related_name='orders'
    )

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
  order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  price =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
  quantity = models.IntegerField(null = True)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my data is already save in these Models now when i fetch order then i want to see Order product data also how can i see these data ?

again 1 order has multi order products

i try this

abc = Order.object.get(id = 1)

now how can i see the related products and its quantity and price?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

abc = Order.object.get(id = 1)

OrdProducts = abc.product.all()

Comment: not working if i want to print price and quantity then its not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
OrdProducts = abc.product.all()
for ord in OrdProducts:
    print(ord.product)
    print(ord.price)
    print(ord.quantity)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.